# JSF Managed Beans not working with spring security filter

Tags: jsf-2, dependency-injection, spring-security

I stumbled upon an issue in my jsf spring application.
After a successfull setup i added spring security to my application and suddenly the injection of @ManagedProperty in jsf beans stopped working. More specifically it turns that properties injected like this are null when using them.

I am using jsf 2.1, spring 3.1 (core + security)

The config looks like this:
 web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

</web-app>
```

FacesServlet is the default servlet dispatcher.

in the faces config i added

```
<application>
        <el-resolver>
                org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
```

...

The jsf managed bean looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
public class InterviewForm {

    @ManagedProperty (value="#{springInterviewHelper}")
    private SpringInterviewHelper springInterviewHelper;
```

...

The springInterviewHelper ends null with the springSecurityFilterChain added in web.xml. If i remove that filter all is working fine, except for the fact that i cannot make use of spring security :). Checked with debug and the only modifications in the stack trace are related to the security filtering so this might cause the injection failure. 
I'd like to use, if possibly, the jsf annotations and not those of spring because i can make use of @ViewScoped and other cosy things of jsf managed beans. Is this possible? What could cause the injection failure?

Thanks a lot,
Marius

Comment: My guess, you aren't loading your other application context xml file. Looksl ike you are only loading your spring security related configuration.

Comment: applicationContext.xml is added by

Comment: <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param> in the web.xml. If i would'nt add that i should have other config problems related to hibernate for example

Comment: It works now :), i just figured what you meant, applicationContext was loaded actually by  default until i added context-param tag. Now it seems i have to mention it explicitly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContextLoaderListener` by default loads an xml file called applicationContext.xml from inside the WEB-INF directory. As soon as you specify a `context-param` named *contextConfigLocation* this default doesn't apply anymore. Also see the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#web-integration-common).

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The configuration above will lead to loading **ONLY** the mentioned configuration file, it will not load the applicationContext.xml file anymore. Now you can solve this easily by simply adding the aformentioned file to the `param-value` tag.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

That should do the trick.